# Including plugins in Cocoa frameworks

Tags: macos, cocoa

In the build process of an OS X framework I have a `Copy Files`build step, which copies 2 bundles to the PlugIns destination.

When I look in the built framework, they end up in *Framework*/Versions/A/Resources.

The related step in the build process:

> PBXCp
>   /Users/nephilim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graphing_Fun-egwutjdrujbsecgqukeyejeljxoo/Build/Products/Debug/GPHPieChart.bundle
>   /Users/nephilim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graphing_Fun-egwutjdrujbsecgqukeyejeljxoo/Build/Products/Debug/Grapher.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GPHPieChart.bundle
>       cd "/Users/nephilim/Documents/Development/Cocoa Projects/Graphing Fun"
>       builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/nephilim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graphing_Fun-egwutjdrujbsecgqukeyejeljxoo/Build/Products/Debug/GPHPieChart.bundle
>   /Users/nephilim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Graphing_Fun-egwutjdrujbsecgqukeyejeljxoo/Build/Products/Debug/Grapher.framework/**Versions/A/Resources**

When I run the code below, I get the folder *Framework*/Plugins:

```
[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] builtInPlugInsPath]
```

As such, I can't use my plugins this way.  Is this an expected result, or a bug?

Context: I'd like to built my framework as basic as possible and extend it with plugins over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**

I tried using "PlugIns" as the destination for the copy files phase and it doesn't seem to work, Using "Wrapper" as the destination with "PlugIns" as the subpath *does* work however.

[image]

---

**previous answer**

Change your copy files phase to copy your plugins to the plugins path...

[image]

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing, which doesn't seem to work (I added the build output to my question).  It seems a framework does not have a PlugIns destination.

Comment: try a custom path then?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I've filed a bug on Radar (15749401).